# Haskell: create Function instance

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I'm currently learning Haskell from the ever awesome [Haskell from first principles](https://haskellbook.com/), and while trying to check the functor instances for each datatype using QuickCheck, I've stumbled against a mayor problem creating a [`Function`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.13.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#t:Function) instance for my `Four` datatype:

```
data Four' a b = Four' a a a b deriving (Eq,Show)
instance Function (Four' a b) where
  function =  let
                  injection :: (Function a, Function b) => (Four' a b) -> (a,a,a,b)
                  injection (Four' x1 x2 x3 z1) = (x1,x2,x3,z1)
                  surjection :: (Function a, Function b) => (a,a,a,b) -> (Four' a b)
                  surjection (x1,x2,x3,z1) = (Four' x1 x2 x3 z1)
              in functionMap injection surjection
```

which throws the following error:

```
Error: • No instance for (Function a) arising from a use of ‘functionMap’
  Possible fix:
    add (Function a) to the context of
      the type signature for:
        function :: forall b1. (Four' a b -> b1) -> Four' a b :-> b1
      or the instance declaration
• In the expression: functionMap injection surjection
```

Also, what is exactly the difference between trying to create a `Function` instance and an [`Arbitrary`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.13.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#t:Arbitrary) instance if they both generate functions?

Comment: @chi - I also haven't come across it, but as ever Hoogle has all the answers. It's apparently part of QuickCheck, and the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.13.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#t:Function) is readily available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some doubts that's really what you want. Some explanation of what you are trying to do which requires `Function` would help us tell whether that's the case.

But to answer the technical question that's already there, `Function` (and `CoArbitrary`, which you will also need if you actually need `Function`) have default, generic implementations, so you don't need to do or understand any of it.

1. Derive `Generic`
2. Write empty instances of `Function` and `CoArbitrary`

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import GHC.Generics (Generic)
import Test.QuickCheck

data Four a b = ... deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)  -- Derive generic

-- Default implementations
instance (Function a, Function b) => Function (Four a b)
instance (CoArbitrary a, CoArbitrary b) => CoArbitrary (Four a b)
```

> Also,what is exactly the difference between trying to create a Function instance and an arbitrary instance if they both generate functions?

- `Arbitrary a`: "how to generate and shrink values of type `a`"
- `CoArbitrary a`+`Function a`: "how to generate and shrink values of type `a -> b` (for suitably constrained `b`)"

These are not the same.